# How do you paint interior doors easily

Tags: doors, painting

I need to paint several interior doors  How can I do this easily.  Most doors are in carpeted rooms.

Also, do you paint the bottom/top surface too for non-humid rooms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a roller to get the most Paint onto the door, only for 1/3rd of the door at a time & immediately Tip or Lay that area off. Tipping or Laying off is using a Paint Brush in the direction of the wood grain or simulated wood grain. Meaning, you even get the meeting joints perfect as well. You never want to just roller a door or trimwork, it looks horrible & is a very obvious Bad Paint Job.

Only Paint the top & bottom of the door if they've never been Painted & then only after a Primer coat & only every 20-years. They just need to be sealed but they don't need any regular refreshing that may hinder operation of the door.

Never Paint the locksets nor their latches, tape them or best is to spend the 1-minute it takes to remove them. If you don't want to remove the door & the top & bottom don't need Paint, then tape the hinges & even overly tape them to trim the tape off with a utility knife. Priming & Painting under the hinges, latch(es) & inside the lockset holes should also be done once & then every 20-years.

Comment: Do you have a special roller for oil based paint?

Comment: I don't, no. I don't touch the stuff anymore. But, the classic Mohair or Lambswool are still the best for clean-up. Though, I still haven't tried the Microfiber covers yet for anything. I'll be finishing up my pack of regular covers late this year & hopefully see if the pretty good hype about Microfiber is true for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Unscrew 'em from the hinges, remove the knobs, lay them flat next to each other, and use a roller. Turn 'em over when dry and do it again on the other side, then repeat until they look great.

Comment: Rolled paint on doors can look wrong - the rolled texture isn't what you expect on a door. Traditionally you want brush strokes in line with the door components. If your doors are totally flat, rolling is probably fine and in any case it's just an aesthetic concern.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the doors and the quality of paint. Flat doors and crappy paint benefit best from rolling. Doors with complicated textures and inlaid panels will benefit from using good-quality paint and brushing it on. I happen to have flat doors and I'm a cheap bastard, so rolling it is for me.